# i want to display only "about me" of mysite of a person in the page

Tags: my-site

i want to display only "about me" of my-site of a person in the page.
Planning to display in a simple sharepoint aspx page or add the hyperlink if any in a list and display as data view.
How can i get a link of "about me" of person from "my-site" sharepoint 2010.